# Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'. >

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, compiler-warnings

When i try to compile this library 'org.brunocvcunha.instagram4j:instagram4j:1.5' i get

Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'. > More than one file was found with OS independent path 'log4j.properties'

any idea how to fix this ? I created new project just to test this library so this is the first library i try to compile.

I've searched through internet and only thing i found for this error is to add this:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
}
```

But this doesnt help. Any idea how to fix this error ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try excluding the log4j.properties with this:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'log4j.properties'
    // or use:
    // exclude 'path/of/log4j/log4j.properties'
}
```

Or, you can try excluding the log4j from the dependency with the following line:

```
dependencies {
   ...
   compile ('org.brunocvcunha.instagram4j:instagram4j:1.5') {
    exclude group: "log4j", module: "log4j"
   }
}
```